# Comprare json string in golang

Tags: go

I have two JSON strings I want to compare. I don't know how to it

First string

```
{"timestamp":"2021-10-26T15:09:35.322019337Z","prices":[{"country":"fr","price":{"recommended":0}},{"country":"at","price":{"recommended":0}},{"country":"de","price":{"recommended":0}}]}
```

Second string

```
{"timestamp":"2021-10-26T15:09:35.322019337Z","prices":[{"country":"fr","price":{"recommended":0}},{"country":"de","price":{"recommended":0}},{"country":"at","price":{"recommended":0}}]}
```

as you can see there is a different order in the array.

Answer (score 4):

You can unmarshal them, and use `reflect.DeepEqual`:

```
var v1, v2 interface{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(s1),&v1)
json.Unmarshal([]byte(s2),&v2)
if reflect.DeepEqual(v1,v2) {
   // They are the same
} else {
   // They are different
}
```

There are also other JSON comparison packages out there.

Comment: Unmarshal will use a `map` to store key-values, and the ordering for a map is unspecified. However, `reflect.DeepEqual` will compare maps ignoring ordering. Thus, this approach will return "equal" for JSON data that differ by order only.

Comment: Are u sure solution because when try your solution, I still getting an error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I am using this code for testing, test result is an error, says they are not same
your code is working but not the right way

Comment: The two JSON inputs are not the same. The ordering of the array is different. Ordering is significant for a JSON array. Ordering is not significant for a JSON object.

Comment: I understood but , how can I control both arrays are same

Comment: You have to recursively compare the unmarshaled maps, and when you come to an array, compare the array equivalence without ordering.

Comment: I will try to do like your suggestion but I couldn't access the array for that part how can I do that

Comment: `v1.(map[string]interface{})["prices"].([]interface{})` would give you the prices array.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple method for comparing strings:

```golang
    if strings.Compare(string1, string2) != 0 {
        return errors.New("strings don't match")
    }
```

Comment: This isn't applicable to JSON as the order of the props is not guaranteed.

Comment: If you are worried about order, you can Base64 encode the two JSON strings and compare that.

Comment: I don't see how base64 encode solves this. The order of the props would not be sorted through encoding the raw string, and if you have differing orders pre-encode, you'd have different resultant encodings post-encode.